# Caching in python by change of members

Tags: python, caching

I have a class with some members, and some methods that access those members.
I want to cache the methods, but every time one of the members change they shouldn't access the cache but run again instead.
It is something like is_changed flag for every member. Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: Is the method a simple getter or does it return some complex calculation based on the member?

Comment: Not a simple getter I'm afraid

Comment: So you're looking to cache the result of the method and only recalculate when the member(s) on which it depends have changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following to generate a unique hash for each object:

```
try:
    import numpy as np
    has_np=True
except ImportError:
    has_np=False

def hash_any(value, hv=None):
    hv = hv or 0
    if value is None or isinstance(value, (str, unicode, int, long, float, bool)):
        hv = hash(value) ^ hv
    elif  has_np and np.isscalar(value):
        hf = hash(value) ^ hv
    elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple, set)):
        for x in value:
            hv = hash_any(x, hv)
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for k,v in value.iteritems():
            hv = hash_any(k, hv)
            hv = hash_any(v, hv)
    elif isinstance(value, slice):
        # Hash a tuple of the slice components
        hv = hash((value.start, value.stop, value.step)) ^ hv
    elif isinstance(value, object):
        hv = hash_any(value.__dict__, hv)

    return hv
```

Then, given an object like:

```
class MyObj(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.memb1 = 'blar'
        self.memb2 = 2124
        self.memb3 = {'a':2,'b':'some'}
```

You can compare the hash at different times to determine if change to any member has occurred:

```
In [1]: cls = MyObj()

In [2]: h1 = hash_any(cls)

In [3]: h1
Out[3]: -4385883409912780426

In [4]: cls.memb1 = 'dog'

In [4]: h2 = hash_any(cls)

In [5]: h2
Out[5]: 3758072334382950160

In [6]: cls.memb3['b'] = 'top'

In [7]: h3 = hash_any(cls)

In [8]: h3
Out[8]: 4138015896510837430
```

If you only wanted to hash on some members of the object, you could run the hash on each individually and then combine them with the `^` operator.  This could even be done as a method of the object itself.

```
class MyObj(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.memb1 = 'blar'
        self.memb2 = 2124
        self.memb3 = {'a':2,'b':'some'}

    def myhash(self):
        h = 0
        tohash = ['memb1', 'memb2']
        for m in tohash:
            h = h ^ hash_any(getattr(self, m))

        return h
```

And then compare `myobj.myhash` over time.